# Transforming Callbacks to RxJava Observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Just started messing around with RxJava, so i am a total newbie at it.

I have a question about the correct approach or any possible solutions to the following problem. I have searched a lot on Google but i do not seem to find any appropriate solutions, just general ideas.

I have a class that does some work and has it's own interface, lets name it *AClass*. Now there is a BClass that implements the beforementioned interface. On the *onActivityResult* of *BClass*, if the requestCode matches the request code we provided, then the *AClass* calls *aClassInstance.handleActivityResult(..)* and does some things. Then it reports back using its interface.

How would someone approach this with RxJava Observables?

My only try at the moment is to transform the *handleActivityResult(..)* into an *Observable* and then implement an *Observer* interface and instantiating a subscription object in the overrided onActivityResult of *BClass* which apparently is an *Activity*. But i need to check if the subscription is null or unsubscribed before instantiating, which as a consequence instantiates the subscription only once, and then the Observer stops receiving any more objects.

I also read about *RxBus* implementations. I am not quite sure if that would be a good approach, cause it got me a little bit confused with the Subjects.

Thanks a lot in advance for any insights you can provide. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get an idea of what you really want, but try to help you.
Am I get you right? Your class AClassInstance whant to know, when the onActivityResult of BClass happened? If all like that, you don`t have to implement "Ainterface" by both classes. You need just listener of when "onActivityResult" will happens:

```
import rx.Observable;


public class ExampleObservers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CallbackReceiver receiver = new CallbackReceiver();
    ActivityProducer activity = new ActivityProducer();
    activity.setListener(receiver);
    activity.onActivityResult(444, 0);
  }
}

class CallbackReceiver implements ActivityProducer.RequestCodeProducer {

  @Override public void handleActivityResult(Observable<Integer> requestObservable) {
    requestObservable.map(it -> {
      System.out.println("here U can do some extra things with your " + it + " number ...");
      return it;
    }).subscribe(res -> System.out.println("Hello requestCode = " + res));
  }
}

class ActivityProducer {
  interface RequestCodeProducer {
    void handleActivityResult(Observable<Integer> requestCode);
  }

  private RequestCodeProducer listener;

  public void setListener(RequestCodeProducer listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  /*
  * . . . . . . .. .. . . .
  * Your activity`s methods
  * */

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode/*, Intent data*/) {
    //super.onActivityResult();
    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(requestCode));

    if (listener != null) {
      listener.handleActivityResult(observable);
    }
  }
}
```

If you run this in IDE, you will see output "Hello requestCode = 444". So, all works fine, and you get your callback.

Comment: AClass defines an interface that BClass has to implement. Then BClass calls aClassInstance.handleActivityResult() and AClass after doing some work, has to report results back to BClass through that interface. Is that something that can be substitute by RxJava or is interfaces the only way around it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with RxJava in way creating something like hot observers [good example, but not in Java](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)
And more convenient way, I think - use RxBus. Check this [nice post](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/) of Kaushik Gopal. Hope it will help you.